# Show randow image on each loop of foreach without it duplication in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random, foreach, duplicates

I have 10 images which is stored as an array.
Also I have a foreach which generate me 10 items.
My goal is to add random image from this array to each of my item that is generated by foreach, furthermore images shouldn't be duplicated.

For ex.:

1 item - img1.jpg;

2 item - img3.jpg;

3 item - img9.jpg...
etc.

```
<?php
    $rss = simplexml_load_file('https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/q/blockchain/blockchain?ned=us&hl=en&gl=US');

    $images = array('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg', 'img5.jpg', 'img6.jpg', 'img7.jpg', 'img8.jpg', 'img9.jpg', 'img10.jpg');
    shuffle ($images);

    foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            echo $image."<br/>"."<br/>";
        }
        echo $item->title."<br/>";
        echo $item->link."<br/>";
        echo $item->pubDate."<br/>";
    }
?>
```

This code returns me random images for items but sometimes they are duplicated.

Is it possible to make it within PHP?

Comment: random numbers can be duplicated as long as you dont check by yourself if a number already exisits

Comment: I know it. Thats why I'm asking how can I do this in PHP?

Comment: shuffle the array and pop one off the end in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like @jeroen said you only need to shuffle the array and the array initialization should be outside the foreach!

```
$images = array('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg', 'img5.jpg', 
'img6.jpg', 'img7.jpg', 'img8.jpg', 'img9.jpg', 'img10.jpg');
shuffle ($images);
foreach ($images as $image) {
   print $image;
}
```

Applying this to your case :

```
<?php
$rss = simplexml_load_file('https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/q/blockchain/blockchain?ned=us&hl=en&gl=US');

$images = array('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg', 'img5.jpg', 'img6.jpg', 'img7.jpg', 'img8.jpg', 'img9.jpg', 'img10.jpg');
shuffle ($images);
$i = 0;
foreach ($rss->channel->item $item) {

    echo $images[$i]."<br/>"."<br/>";
    echo $item->title."<br/>";
    echo $item->link."<br/>";
    echo $item->pubDate."<br/>";
    $i++;
}
```

?>

Comment: Thank you.
I modified my code due to your answer.
However I still have a problem. When I put your foreach into mine I got the result like: 10 images + item1, 10 images + item2. Is there any chance to fix it?

Comment: There's no *your foreach and mine, there's only one foreach*, let me add some insights to my answer

Comment: It must be the key which is not correct, try with a variable, I updated my answer